# IPython - Hide traceback when SystemExit is raised

Tags: ipython

I'm surprised no one asked this issue before, but somehow I couldn't find an answer.

When raising `SystemExit` in a simple `my_script.py`.

```py
import sys

sys.exit(2)
```

No traceback is displayed when running `python my_script.py`, as explained in [python doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#SystemExit):

> SystemExit: When it is not handled, the Python interpreter exits; no stack traceback is printed.

However when running with `ipython`, a traceback is printed:

```
$ ipython my_script.py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SystemExit                                Traceback (most recent call last)
my_script.py in <module>
      2 import sys
      3 
----> 4 sys.exit(2)

SystemExit: 2
```

This is an issue when using `argparse` as `parser.parse_args()` call `sys.exit()` if parsing fail. So user see an unhelpful `SystemExit: 2` rather than the error message printed above the traceback.

A workaround is to use `os._exit` but this feels very hacky and might not properly cleanup.

Is there a `ipython` flag which would silence/hide the traceback when `SystemExit` is raised, like with standard `python` interpreter ?

Comment: I use `--TerminalInteractiveShell.xmode=Plain` in my `ipython` script to alter this behavior.  There are alternative values.  I think it can also changed within the session, though I forget the details.  (I get this kind of `systemExit` when testing `argparse` code.)

Comment: Found it, there's a `%xmode` magic.

Comment: I'm not sure this solve my issue. `ipython my_script.py --TerminalInteractiveShell.xmode=Plain` still display the traceback, but just in a more compact way. I'm looking into not displaying the traceback at all, like standard python interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample session with `xmode` 'plain':

```
In [1]: import argparse
In [2]: parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
In [3]: parser.add_argument('foo')
Out[3]: _StoreAction(option_strings=[], dest='foo', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)
In [4]: import sys; sys.argv
Out[4]: 
['/usr/local/bin/ipython3',
 '--pylab',
 'qt',
 '--nosep',
 '--term-title',
 '--InteractiveShellApp.pylab_import_all=False',
 '--TerminalInteractiveShell.xmode=Plain']
In [5]: parser.parse_args()
usage: ipython3 [-h] foo
ipython3: error: unrecognized arguments: --pylab --nosep --term-title --InteractiveShellApp.pylab_import_all=False --TerminalInteractiveShell.xmode=Plain
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.
SystemExit: 2

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py:3426: UserWarning: To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.
  warn("To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.", stacklevel=1)
In [6]: parser.parse_args([])
usage: ipython3 [-h] foo
ipython3: error: the following arguments are required: foo
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.
SystemExit: 2

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py:3426: UserWarning: To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.
  warn("To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.", stacklevel=1)
```

This shows the error message produced by the parser, followed by the capture and traceback.  This allows me to continue interactively.

With plain interpreter, I get the message followed by an exit.

```
2310:~/mypy$ python3
Python 3.8.5 (default, Jan 27 2021, 15:41:15) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import argparse
>>> parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> parser.add_argument('foo');
_StoreAction(option_strings=[], dest='foo', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)
>>> parser.parse_args()
usage: [-h] foo
: error: the following arguments are required: foo
2311:~/mypy$
```

For me the whole purpose of using `ipython` is to try multiple things, without it quitting on me.  Otherwise I'd run the script without the interactive layer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However it doesn't really answer the question of how to hide the traceback when `SystemExit` is raised. 
For your second point, I which I could use regular Python interpreter unfortunately it is not an option due for reason independent of me.